# Proving $\int^{t}_{-\infty}f(x)e^{-2\pi iz(x-t)}dx$ is bounded in $\Bbb{C}$ (i.e. respect to $z$)

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform

> Suppose $f$ is continuous and of moderate decrease, i.e. $\exists A\; s.t.|f(x)|\leq \frac{A}{1+x^2} \; \forall x \in \Bbb{R}$ and $\hat f(\zeta)=0 ,\;\forall \zeta \in \Bbb{R}$. For each fixed real number $t$, let $A(z) =
>  \int^{t}_{-\infty}f(x)e^{-2\pi iz(x-t)}dx$ and $B(z) =
>  -\int^{\infty}_{t}f(x)e^{-2\pi iz(x-t)}dx$, define $F$ in $\Bbb{C}$ s.t. $F=A$ in the closed upper half plane and $F=B$ in the lower half
>   plane. Prove that $F$ is entire and bounded.

I know how to prove $F$ is entire, by simply apply symmetry principle. But I have trouble in proving that $F$ is bounded. I think for $Im(z)<0$ I can use $F(z)=B(z)$ to estimate $F(z)$ when $|z|\to \infty$ and use $F(z)=A(z)$ for $Im(z)>0$, but I simply lost in the middle. Could you please help me? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "moderate decrease"? Do you mean "rapid decrease", i.e. the space $\mathcal S (\Bbb R)$? If so, then the Fourier transform is an isomorphism on this space, so $\hat f = 0$ implies $f = 0$.

Comment: @AlexM. Sorry for ambiguity. Edited.

Comment: With these clarifications, $f$ may be viewed as a tempered distribution, i.e. as an element of $\mathcal S' (\Bbb R)$, a space on which again the Fourier transform is an isomorphism. so again $f$ must be $0$.

Comment: Actually it is an exercise from my complex analysis course, so I think I am expected to use to skills in complex analysis (in fact, the problem asked me to prove that $F$ is bounded and entire, in order to prove $F = 0$ (by Liouville's theorem) )

Comment: How did you prove that $F$ is an integer function? Did you show that you were holomorphic first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If boundedness is the only thing bothering you, then notice that for $\Im z \ge 0$ (and $z = a + b \Bbb i$) we have, for every $t \in \Bbb R$,

$$|F(z)| = |A(z)| = \left| \int \limits _{-\infty} ^t f(x) \ \Bbb e ^{2 \pi \Bbb i z (x-t)} \Bbb d x \right| \le \int \limits _{-\infty} ^t \left| f(x) \ \Bbb e ^{2 \pi \Bbb i z (x-t)} \right| \Bbb d x = \int \limits _{-\infty} ^t |f(x)| \ \Bbb e ^{2 \pi b (x-t)} \ \Bbb d x \le \int \limits _{-\infty} ^t \frac A {1 + x^2} \cdot 1 \ \Bbb d x = A \left( \arctan t + \frac \pi 2 \right) .$$

(We have $\Bbb e ^{2 \pi b (x-t)} \le 1$ because $b \ge 0$ and $x \le t$.)

Similarly, for $\Im z \le 0$ you will get

$$|F(z)| \le A \left( \frac \pi 2 - \arctan t \right) ,$$

whence it follows that $|F|$ is bounded by $A \max \left\{ \arctan t + \frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2 - \arctan t \right\}$, which no longer depends on $z$.

---

There is something interesting, though: since $f$ may be viewed as a tempered distribution, and since $\hat f = 0$, it follows that $f = 0$, hence $F=0$.

Comment: But $b \ge 0$, $x-t \le 0$ give $-2\pi b(x-t) \ge 0$, correct?

Comment: @User8128: I had a "minus" too much, because $- \Bbb i (b \Bbb i) = b$, not $-b$. Fixed.

Comment: Ah, got it! You missed the sign in the exponent at the beginning. Should be $e^{-2\pi iz(x-t)}$. Great proof!

Comment: Thank you so much! I have not notice that $x \leq t$ is useful. How silly I am.

Comment: @AlexM. Alex, $F(z;t)$ depends on the real parameter $t$.  While it is true that $\lim_{t\to -\infty}F(z;t)=0$ for $\text{Im}(z)<0$ and $\lim_{t\to \infty}F(z;t)=0$ for $\text{Im}(z)>0$, as you correctly showed, how does one conclude that $F(z;t)=0$?

Comment: @Dr.MV: You are absolutely right, I have eliminated that paragraph. It remains true, though, that $F=0$, with the argument based upon the injectivity of the Fourier transform on $\mathcal S ' (\Bbb R)$.

Comment: @AlexM. No worry.  You're one of the "good" ones on MSE!  And I liked the reference to tempered distributions.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$ \left\lvert \int^t_{-\infty} f(x) e^{-2\pi i z(x-t)} dx \right \rvert \le \int^t_{-\infty}\lvert f(x) \rvert \left \lvert e^{-2\pi i z(x-t)} \right \rvert  dx \le A \int^t_{-\infty} \frac{\left \lvert e^{-2\pi i z(x-t)}\right \rvert}{1+x^2} dx$$ Now $\left \lvert e^{-2\pi i z(x-t)} \right \rvert = e^{2\pi b(x-t)}$ where $b= \text{Im}\{z\} \ge 0$ since this definition applies for $z$ in the upper half plane. Then $$\left\lvert \int^t_{-\infty} f(x) e^{-2\pi i z(x-t)} dx \right \rvert \le Ae^{-2\pi bt}\int^t_{-\infty } \frac{e^{2\pi bx}}{1+x^2}dx.$$ The right hand side is a continuous function of $b$, hence bounded on any compact set: $b \in [0,R], \,\, R > 0$ . Thus it suffices to bound the expression for large $b$. For $b$ away from zero, we see $$\int^t_{-\infty } \frac{e^{2\pi bx}}{1+x^2}dx \le \int^t_{-\infty} e^{2\pi b x} dx = \left.\frac{1}{2\pi b}e^{2\pi b x}\right|_{x=-\infty}^{x=t} = \frac{e^{2\pi bt}}{2\pi b}.$$ Plugging this in above gives $$\left\lvert \int^t_{-\infty} f(x) e^{-2\pi i z(x-t)} dx \right \rvert \le \frac{A}{2\pi b} \le \frac{A}{2\pi} $$ for $b\ge 1$. Combine this with whatever bound you get for $b \in [0,1]$ to see that $A(z)$ is bounded. A nearly identical manipulation shows that $B(z)$ is bounded for $\text{Im}\{z\} \le 0$.